# Excel Query from access.accdb file on password-protected site

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So, I can download an .accdb file from a sharepoint site within our company, using a POST request and an MSXML2.ServerHTTP60 object, supplying the intranet password etc. all within Excel VBA. Cool!

With that downloaded file I can run queries against it using code like this:

```
Dim connXXX As ADODB.Connection
Dim aQuery As String
Dim p As String
Dim res As Object
Dim connStr As String
    p = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testBASE1.accdb"
    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & p
    aQuery = "SELECT Header1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 4"
Set connXXX = New ADODB.Connection
    connXXX.Open connStr

Set res = connXXX.Execute(aQuery)
MsgBox res.Fields(0)
```

What I REALLY want to do though is cut out downloading the file altogether, so I can run a query against the .accdb file that's hosted on the intranet.

I've been trying a few variations on this code using .connectionString or putting in "URL=" instead of datasource... all to no avail; I can't figure out where I'd put the intranet username/password... please help! I always get my errors around the connXXX.open part of the code.

1) Is this even possible and
2) How?!

Broken code:

```
'ppp = "http://the_intranet_address_and_filename_with_extension"
'ppp = "URL=http://the_intranet_address_and_filename_with_extension"
    '' I've tried both above

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
aQuery = "SELECT Header1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 4"
connStrBig = connStr & "Data Source=" & ppp

connXXX.Provider = connStr
connXXX.ConnectionString = ppp
connXXX.Open
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to password protected Access DBs via VBA is tricky- I've found that the syntax suggested by Microsoft doesn't even work... I've gotten DAO connections to work with password protected DBs, see code below- hopefully you can fiddle the same syntax to work with ADO, or just switch all together:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dbPath As String
Dim aQuery As String
Dim pword As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testBASE1.accdb"
pword = "password"
aQuery = "SELECT Header1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 4"

Set db = Access.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(dbPath, True, False, ";PWD=" & pword)
Set rs = db.Execute(aQuery)
rs.MoveFirst
MsgBox rs.Fields(0)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode